# ExpressValidator no pasa valor

Tags: nodejs, express, validación, express.js

Estoy tratando de realizaar la validacion de un formulacio con express-validator pero no me estaria funcionando, estoy probando con una validacion custom a ver si llega el valor pero no logro encontrar el error.

Archivo de ruteo

```
const { body } = require('express-validator');
const validationProfile = [
    body('name').custom(value => {
        console.log(value)
        return true;
    }),
]

module.exports = () => {
    
    router.post('/users/edit-profile', authController.verificarUsuario, validationProfile, upload.single('imgProfile'), userController.editProfile)

    return router;
}
```

Formulario de validacion

```
<main class="contenedor">
    <form action="/users/edit-profile" method="POST" class="default-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="campo">
            <label>Nombre</label>
            <input value="{{user.name}}" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Tu Nombre" required>
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <label>E-mail</label>
            <input value="{{user.email}}" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Tu E-mail" required>
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Tu Password">
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <label>Imagen</label>
            <input type="file" name="imgProfile">
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-azul" value="Guardar Cambios">
        </div>
    </form>
</main>
```

Pero en la consola directamente me arroja **undefine**

Segun la doc de express-validator me deberia arrojar el nombre que el usuario envia en el campo

Comment: Ahora que hago memoria, creo que tuve un problema parecido hace tiempo. Express Validator y multer [no se llevan muy bien](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/783). ¿Que tal si [colocas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63678454/8838721) el middleware de `multer` antes de las validaciones? Es decir, `upload.single('imgProfile')` antes de `authController.verificarUsuario`. ¿Se imprime el valor del campo?

Comment: El tema es que con express validator quiero hacer la validacion del archivo imgProfile, solamente que borre todas las validaciones porque no esta validando, por lo que necesito primero validar y despues subir el archivo si pasa ese middleware

Comment: ¿Pero probaste al menos si llegan los campos  a las validaciones con ese cambio? Ya eso sería un avance. Luego tu mismo podrías hasta borrar el archivo subido en caso de errores. No es lo mismo que funcione y luego mejorarlo y depurar, a que no funcione.

Comment: Acabo de probar con la siguiente linea
router.post('/users/edit-profile', validationProfile, userController.editProfile)
Y ahi si esta llegando los valores a la validacion

Comment: Podra ser un problema con el midd de autentificacion? o el de multer ? vos decis?

Comment: Ya encontre el problema, pero el tema es como lo soluciono, el tema es cuando agrego enctype="multipart/form-data" al form. A partir de ese momento llega todo undefine al express validator

Comment: Es precisamente por ello que multer debe ir antes de las validaciones, porque como envías el form usando `multipart/form-data` para poder subir archivos, el que sabe decodificar ese tipo de body es multer, no express validations. La verdad no sabría decirte cómo solucionarlo. Hace ya bastante no uso express, ando con puro java ahora. En su momento opté por borrar el archivo subido si detectaba un error en el formulario.

Comment: Y como puedo borrar el archivo? perdon pero soy bastante nuevo en este tema

Comment: Cuando se sube un archivo con multer, multer agregará una propiedad `file` a tu request a la que puedes acceder mediante `req.file` en tu controlador o donde sea que manejes los errores. En `req.file.path` está el path del archivo subido. Si hay errores, puedes eliminar ese archivo con `fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path);`. Alternativamente puedes usar su versión asincrónica `fs.unlink(req.file.path)`. (Por si no la conocias, `fs` es la librería nativa de node para manejar el sistemas de archivos.)

Comment: De cualquier manera, espera un poco. Acá hay mucha gente que programa en node, tal vez entre hoy y mañana te den una mejor respuesta. También puedes comentar de tu problema en el [chat de stackoverflow en español](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol).